# How I can show column name in postman using Jpa if I am writing native query having only specific columns

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

- I made a native query in my repository which only give specific columns as output.

  @Query(value = "SELECT installation_id,description,checklist_steps,creation_date,location,status FROM installation_details", nativeQuery = true)
  List < Object > findCustomInstallation();
- But the response I am getting on postman is only showing me the data inside columns so how I can show column name also?
- Note:- I am not using my model as it is having one to one mapping of other table also and if I run query using my model it is also showing me data of other table on postman that is why I used Object instead of model.
- The response I am getting is this

> ```
> > {
> >     "status": 1,
> >     "message": "Successfully Fetched",
> >     "myObjectList": [
> >         [
> >             1,
> >             "traffic project",
> >             "13",
> >             "2021-01-30T06:57:34.000+0000",
> >             "Delhi",
> >             1
> >         ],
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use projections to get this working.

Create an interface with only getters

```
public interface InstallationDetailsProjection 
{
    Long getInstallation_id();
    String getDescription();
//similar for other fields
}
```

Then add alias to your native query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT installation_id as installation_id,description as description //more fields
 FROM installation_details", nativeQuery = true) List < InstallationDetailsProjection > findCustomInstallation();
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Ok let me try sir